# When I use SharePoint's export to spreadsheet (Excel), not all the columns appear

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint, moss

We have several SharePoint (MOSS) lists with 100's of items so we use 'export to spreadsheet' to do the heavy editing. But, in the spreadsheet not all of the list columns appear. One example is all columns of the 'publishing HTML' type cannot be edited (or even seen) in either Excel 2003 or the web datasheet view. But, an SSIS can export/import these columns without issue.

Is there a way to use Excel 2003/2007 or Access 03/07 to edit these columns. Is there another way to connect to these columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to use any Office 2003 or 2007 products to edit Publishing HTML fields in SharePoint 2007.

You can, however, download the beta version of Office 2010. You can then connect to the SharePoint lists using Linked Tables in Access which will allow you to edit Publishing HTML fields (which you couldn't do in any previous version).